# Render multiple blade view sections on ajax request

Tags: php, ajax, laravel, render, laravel-blade

When request is ajax, i am rendering content section and inserting it to DOM. It is working as expected.

However.. i can't find out the way, how to render multiple sections, like `content` and `title` and more in the same time.

**Controller:**

```
public function awesome(Request $request) {
   if($request->ajax()){
       return view('awesome')->renderSections()['content'];
   }
   return view('awesome');
}
```

**Ajax and pushstate**

```
var load = function (url) {
    $.get(url).done(function (data) {
      $("#content").html(data);
    })
};

$(document).on('click', 'a[data-request="push"]', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this),
    url = $this.attr("href"),
    title = $this.attr('title');

    history.pushState({
       url: url,
       title: title
    }, title, url);

    // document.title = title;

    load(url);
});
```

**layouts.app**

```
<title>@yield('title')</title>
<meta name="description" content="@yield('desc')"/>

<a data-request="push" title="AWESOME" href="<?= url('/'); ?>/awesome">Awesome</a>
<a data-request="push" title="RANDOM" href="<?= url('/'); ?>/random">Random</a>

<div id="content">
  @yield('content')
</div>
```

**Blade:**

```
@extends('layouts.app')

@section('title', 'Awesome')
@section('desc', 'About awesome')

@section('content')
  some text from awesome page
@endsection
```

**Question:**

How to render both or more of them in same time? Should i use an array or something else? Please give example or full explanation.

Thanks for any answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can just send a json object of title and content, and then use JS to parse the array and extract both sections. Like so:

**Controller**

```
public function awesome(Request $request) {
   if($request->ajax()){
       $view = view('awesome')->renderSections();
       return response()->json([
           'content' => $view['content'],
           'title' => $view['title'],
       ]);
   }
   return view('awesome');
}
```

**Ajax and pushstate**

```
var load = function (url) {
    $.get(url).done(function (data) {
      $("#content").html(data.content);
      document.title = data.title;
    })
};

$(document).on('click', 'a[data-request="push"]', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $this = $(this),
    url = $this.attr("href"),
    title = $this.attr('title');

    history.pushState({
       url: url,
       title: title
    }, title, url);

    // document.title = title;

    load(url);
});
```

Comment: I already did the same, but instead of returning response, i am encoding view and then in ajax request, i am using ``data = $.parseJSON(data)``. But i think thats same. Maybe response() would be more ``laravel`` thing. How do you think?

Comment: $.parseJson would only work if you return a json string. That is done by the response json method. Secondly, response json also sets the content type to `application/json`. Finally always make sure to return a response or view from your controller rather than a string. It's the technically correct way :)

Comment: Okay, thanks. Banged my head for this one, last two days.